# Template pack expansion with functions

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++20

The code below works as intended.

```
struct A 
{
    template<typename T>
    void do_real_stuff() {}

    template <typename... Types> 
    struct DoStuff;

    template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
    struct DoStuff<Head, Tail...>
    {
        DoStuff(A &base)
        {
            base.do_real_stuff<Head>();
            (base.do_real_stuff<Tail>(), ...);
        }
    };
};
```

struct A allows me to call it like:

```
A a;
DoStuff<int,double,string>(a);
```

But I can't figure out why I can't get the same pattern to work with functions instead of structs.

```
struct B 
{
    template<typename T>
    void do_real_stuff() {}

    template <typename... Types>
    void DoStuff();

    template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
    void DoStuff<Head, Tail...>()
    {
         do_real_stuff<Head>();
         (do_real_stuff<Tail>(), ...);
    }
};
```

Because I want to call it like this:

```
A a;
a.DoStuff<int,double,string>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't partially specialize function templates - only class templates.

But you don't actually have to do that in this example. You're already using a *fold-expression*, just also include the first type:

```cpp
struct B 
{
    template<typename T>
    void do_real_stuff() {}

    template <typename... Types>
    void DoStuff()
    {
         (do_real_stuff<Types>(), ...);
    }
};
```